# sql loop to fill up date between two time stamps

Tags: sql, oracle, date, loops

I want to do something to fill up the dates between two time stamps. For example, someone is admitted in Jan and discharged in Mar, I want to know their stay separately by month, such as,

my original data looks like, 
[image]

then what I want to get is, 
[image]

I know the "loop" should be able to do that in SQL Oracle, but not sure how. Can someone similar with this give some hint and help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. I'd create a calendar table with start and end dates. Then I'd join against that calendar where admission <= calendar.start and discharge >= calendar.end. Play around with that sort of logic for a bit. You don't a loop for this. Just a calendar table and a join.

Comment: For which particular database (version) do you need a solution?

Comment: I'd question why you need to fill in the explicit dates between admission and discharge.  Doing so has triggered my code smell sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
WITH tab AS (
  SELECT 1 ID, to_date('20140105', 'YYYYMMDD') admission, to_date('20140331', 'YYYYMMDD') discharge FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, to_date('20140207', 'YYYYMMDD') admission, to_date('20140212', 'YYYYMMDD') discharge FROM dual
)
*/
SELECT ID, admission, discharge, 
       CASE WHEN trunc(add_months(admission, lvl), 'MM') = trunc(admission, 'MM') 
            THEN admission
            ELSE trunc(add_months(admission, lvl), 'MM') END,
       CASE WHEN trunc(add_months(admission, lvl+1), 'MM') <= trunc(discharge, 'MM') 
            THEN trunc(add_months(admission, lvl+1), 'MM') - 1
            ELSE discharge END
FROM (SELECT lvl FROM (SELECT LEVEL - 1 lvl FROM dual 
                       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 
                                  (SELECT ceil(months_between(MAX(discharge), MIN(admission)))+1 FROM tab))
     ) JOIN tab ON trunc(add_months(admission, lvl), 'MM') <= discharge
ORDER BY ID, lvl;
```

1) Use CONNECT BY level <= N to generate a table with numbers from 0 to N-1 (max difference between months)

2) Join this table with your `tab` to produce the result.